# linux curl+nginx can't request with no keepalive

Tags: curl, nginx

I'm trying to make a status request to localhost and get an error messages in the error.log file. Do you know, how to fix this?
*Or maybe it's just an **informational** message, which will always come with "no keepalive" packets.*

```
/usr/bin/curl --no-keepalive -s -m 3 http://127.0.0.1/server-status
```

/tmp/error.log

```
2014/07/24 06:03:23 [info] 18038#0: *198319 client 127.0.0.1 closed keepalive connection
2014/07/24 06:04:22 [info] 18038#0: *198398 client 127.0.0.1 closed keepalive connection
```

/tmp/access.log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jul/2014:06:03:23 +0400] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 200 110 "-" "curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.15.3 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2"
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jul/2014:06:04:22 +0400] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 200 110 "-" "curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.15.3 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2"
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
error_log       /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
http {
    client_body_timeout     10;
    client_header_timeout   10;
    keepalive_timeout       5 5;
    send_timeout            10;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/localhost

```
server {
    listen localhost;
    server_name nginx_status.localhost;
    access_log      /tmp/access.log;
    error_log       /tmp/error.log info;
    location /server-status {
        stub_status     on;
        allow   127.0.0.1;
        deny    all;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's written "closed keepalive connection". So, It mean, that connection is "keepalive". I don't want keepalive connection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable HTTP keepalive for status connections, if you access it rare enough:

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/localhost

```
server {
    listen localhost;
    server_name nginx_status.localhost;
    access_log      /tmp/access.log;
    error_log       /tmp/error.log info;
    location /server-status {
        stub_status     on;
        keepalive_timeout 0;    # Disable HTTP keepalive
        allow   127.0.0.1;
        deny    all;
    }
}
```

Thanks to duskwuff.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error. The `[info]` in the log message indicates that this message is informational. If you don't want to see these messages, set the log level in the `error_log` directive to a less verbose level, like `notice`, `warn`, or `error`.

Comment: So, you think, it will always come with "no keepalive" packets?

Comment: HTTP keepalive is something separate from, and unrelated to, TCP keepalive packets.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Can I disable HTTP keepalive on "listen localhost" server?

Comment: Yes, I've found, and it helped! "keepalive_timeout 0". Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that disabling HTTP keepalives will decrease your server's performance considerably, as your browser must now make a new connection for every request.